# Reverse for 'index' with keyword arguments '{'username': 'garrett', 'pk': 7}' not found

Tags: python, django

So I know what a reverse is, I just don't understand how the Keyword stuff fits into it. What I am trying to do is enable people to delete only their own posts. The delete button shows up properly on only the users own posts, however when you click "Delete" I'm getting an error, here is the error along with the code. The traceback doesn't highlight anything but if you want to see it or anything else let me know and I can add it. Also haven't been able to find any other questions on this site...

Error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /colorsets/delete/7/
Reverse for 'index' with keyword arguments '{'username': 'garrett', 'pk': 7}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['$']
```

Colorsets App views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from colorsets.forms import ColorForm
from colorsets import models
from colorsets.models import ColorSet
from django.utils import timezone

from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse,reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from braces.views import SelectRelatedMixin
from django.views.generic import (TemplateView,ListView,
                                    DetailView,CreateView,
                                    UpdateView,DeleteView)

# Create your views here.
#def index(request):
#   return render(request,'index.html')

class PostListView(ListView):
    model = ColorSet

    def get_queryset(self):
        return ColorSet.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-published_date')

class CreateColorSetView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'index.html'
    form_class = ColorForm
    model = ColorSet

    def form_valid(self,form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.user = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

class DeletePost(LoginRequiredMixin,SelectRelatedMixin,DeleteView):
    model = models.ColorSet
    select_related = ('user',)
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(user_id=self.request.user.id)

    def delete(self,*args,**kwargs):
        messages.success(self.request,'Post Deleted')
        return super().delete(*args,**kwargs)
```

Colorsets app urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from colorsets import views

app_name = 'colorsets'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^new/$',views.CreateColorSetView.as_view(),name='new_color'),
    url(r'delete/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.DeletePost.as_view(),name='delete'),
]
```

Project urls.py

```
"""colors URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.conf.urls import url, include
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import include
from accounts import views
from colorsets import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$',views.PostListView.as_view(),name='index'),
    url(r'^accounts/',include('accounts.urls',namespace='accounts')),
    url(r'^colorsets/',include('colorsets.urls',namespace='colorsets')),
]
```

Colorset_confirm_delete.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h3>Are you sure you want to delete this post?</h3>

    <div class="posts">
        {% include "colorsets/_post.html" with post=object hide_delete=True %}
    </div>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" value="Confirm Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-large" />
        <a class="btn btn-simple btn-large" href="{% url 'index' username=user.username pk=object.pk %}">Cancel</a>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Colorset_list.html (serving as my index):

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <div class="widget widget-one">
            <div class="widget-content">
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    <p>Welcome, {{ user.username }}</p>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="widget widget-two">
            <p>Widget Two</p>
        </div>

        <div class="widget widget-three">
            <p>Widget Three</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
    {% for colorset in colorset_list %}
            <table class="colorset">
                <tr>
                    <h3 class="set-name">{{ colorset.name }}</h3>
                    <p class="author accent-text">Author: {{ colorset.user }}</p>

                    {% if user.is_authenticated and colorset.user == user %}
                        <a href="{% url 'colorsets:delete' pk=colorset.pk %}" title="delete" class="btn btn-simple">
                            <span class="text-danger icon-label">Delete</span>
                        </a>
                    {% endif %}

                    <td class="color" style="background-color:#{{ colorset.color_one }}">
                    </td>
                    <td class="color" style="background-color:#{{ colorset.color_two }}">
                    </td>
                    <td class="color" style="background-color:#{{ colorset.color_three }}">
                    </td>
                    <td class="color" style="background-color:#{{ colorset.color_four }}">
                    </td>
                    <td class="color" style="background-color:#{{ colorset.color_five }}">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p>#{{ colorset.color_one }}</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>#{{ colorset.color_two }}</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>#{{ colorset.color_three }}</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>#{{ colorset.color_four }}</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>#{{ colorset.color_five }}</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Oh sorry the index is in my project urls `urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$',views.PostListView.as_view(),name='index'),
    url(r'^accounts/',include('accounts.urls',namespace='accounts')),
    url(r'^colorsets/',include('colorsets.urls',namespace='colorsets')),
]`

Comment: You should post that as an update to the question. But it seems that the index view takes no arguments; why are you passing the username to it from your Cancel button?

Comment: `from accounts import views` is hidden by the next line (`from colorsets import views
`) in project's urls.py

Comment: @DanielRoseman I did update the post. And I thought I wanted to do that because it's deleting a specific user's post?

Comment: @PRMoureu What do you mean by "hidden" and how would I fix that?

Comment: what `views` do you expect when you call it next ?

Comment: @PRMoureu So my thought process is that the user would click delete which would bring in the `confirm_delete` template and `DeleteView` to actually delete the post.

Comment: @Garrett But like Daniel Roseman said, the error is coming from the `url` call in the Cancel button.

Comment: @DanielRoseman So I removed the cancel button and now everything works, the only thing is that I now have no cancel button. If it's not too much to ask for, do you have any ideas as to how I might be able to fix the cancel button? If not, all good, thanks for the help.

Comment: @Garrett You don't need to remove the Cancel button, just the arguments you are passing to `url`. Use  `{% url 'index' %}` as href.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida You're that worked. thank you. I got that url tag from a tutorial I followed on the a different project and that's how the person did it, not sure why because it makes no sense. Thanks again everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your main `urls.py` takes no argumemts:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^$',views.PostListView.as_view(),name='index'),
    ...
]
```

You should remove all the passed arguments at the `colorset_confirm_delete.html` and call reverse without them:

```
<a class="btn btn-simple btn-large" href="{% url 'index' %}">Cancel</a>
```

Comment: I was able to figure it out through the comments people posted, but yeah this was right. Thanks